# Blur event not fired after alert in chrome, but can on Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Here is the code [in jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/greencomet90/1ymykz84/)

1.After change text on the textbox, the alert popup appear, click ok, then the blur event is fired and the text change. That work in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome the blur event is not fired and so, the text not change. Why?

2.I observe some curious thing. Change text in textbox, switch to other app (or Ctrl + T new tab), the alert popup appear, click ok, and now the blur event is fired on Chrome. With the isFocus of textbox is false even before the alert, and in blur function. Why is it even fire at all if the textbox has already lost focus?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#id1").val('Original Text');
  $("#id1").blur(function() {
    console.log('When blur fire: Input has focus: ' + $("#id1").is(":focus"));
    actionBlur(jQuery(this));
  });
});

function actionBlur($field) {
  $field.val("Blur fired");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="id1" property="prop1" onchange="scriptAlert();" />
<script>
  var isFocus;

  function scriptAlert() {
      isFocus = $("#id1").is(":focus");
      console.log('Before alert: Input has focus: ' + $("#id1").is(":focus"));
      alert('input has Focus: ' + $("#id1").is(":focus")); console.log('After alert: Input has focus: ' + $("#id1").is(":focus"));
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One small thing -

```
alert('input has Focus: ' + $("#id1").is(":focus");
```

should be -

```
alert('input has Focus: ' + $("#id1").is(":focus"));
```

Your Chrome console should show this error. With that fixed, the script worked OK for me in both Firefox and Chrome (Version 51.0.2704.106 m).

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. But Chrome still not run (version:  51.0.2704.106 m). Firefox run ok. Weird.

Comment: OK, for first part, when you change the text, does it alert in Chrome?

Comment: Yup, it alert in Chrome. But after click ok to turn off the popup, the text in the text box doesn't change. (With Firefox, the text is change by function call by blur event)

Comment: Hmm...strange indeed. Even your fiddle worked properly in my Chrome. Would it be possible for you to check in another machine just to be sure?

Comment: 1 other Chrome work just fine. The other have the same error, blur not fired.